# Is it necessary to use HTTPS for server side requests?

Tags: security, https, httprequest

I'm allowing users to log in to my site using third party credentials (let's call it SocialFoo). Users submit their username and password for SocialFoo via a POST over HTTPS. After the POST is made, on the server side, I validate the credentials via an API call to SocialFoo.

Is there any security benefit to making the API call to SocialFoo via HTTPS rather than HTTP? Since this request is theoretically not exposed to user, is there a security risk beyond packet sniffers at the data center?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, at list while your session is active, some authentication token is transmitted to the server with every your request. To prevent this token from being captured and tampered with while crossing the network, ensure that you use SSL with all pages that require authenticated access.

Comment: This doesn't really address my question. I'm asking about a secondary request done server side - it is in accessible by the user as far as I understand. As I mentioned in the question, the first request is over HTTPS so your comment does not address my question.

Comment: During the first request authentication ticket was sent to the client. For the following requests client sends this ticket back to the server to authenticate this particular request. So these requests definitelly must be secured by https too. Why this not address your question?

Answer (score 0):

**YES**

There is *always* a risk of having information stolen if it is not transmitted securely.  As a general rule of thumb, any and all sensitive data going in or going out should be encrypted.  It is not only a "security benefit" to use HTTPS, but should be a requirement.

Comment: Can you please address the specific risk? I understand your point but am looking for details.

Comment: Someone can be packet sniffing your server, the API service's servers, or any network traffic in-between.  In a shared host, a hack can be used to scan other's logs to steal information.  In a VPS system, recording network traffic can get the information.  There are dozens of ways to hack, sniff, stalk, watch, steal, and record information.  Take your pick.  To say "please address the specific risk", are you asking a question for which volumes of books have been written.  There isn't just ONE risk; there are dozens.  If you don't understand that, try researching cybersecurity in general...

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the answer to your specific question is no. 
SSL encryption is used to protect network traffic while it is transmitted on the network. If both servers are on the same local network and that network is located in a single data center, then the only reason for using ssl is to protect against threats on that network in that data center.
Another question is if it is good security practice to not protect against threats on the local network.

Answer (score 0):

There's not really any risk aside from anyone sniffing the traffic between you and the remote host. SSL protects you from just that when used properly though. Encryption prevents your data from being understood when only observed and authentication lets you know it most likely has not been tampered with.

Your specific question about sniffers at data centers...
If both hosts are located in data center under the same switch, you're probably fine.
If they're not, then you need to ask about VLAN bridging between your two switches, assuming you're renting both switches for both hosts.

If your data center won't let you just up and bridge the two, then you will want to use SSL or any other well used scheme. If you want to see how easy it is to look at traffic under your switch (or even further sometimes), just run tcpdump (Linux) or Wireshark (Windows).

Just be safe, use SSL. There's not really problem with performance these days either, unless you're using 16384 bit keys, are running your own CA and doing real-time CRL checking, and need over 1,000 connections / second. Or, you're using old hardware... in which case, at least use 2048 bit keys.

Also depending on your business or the content of your transmissions, it may be required as a regulation in your country to secure the data or at least make a reasonable attempt at maintaining confidentiality or authentication of some kind.

An added note: You mentioned that since the request isn't exposed to the user, you might not need SSL. SSL protects the user's data. It doesn't do anything to prevent a user from reverse engineering your protocol, tampering with data before it's transmitted, or anything like that. I may be misunderstanding your point, but I figured I would throw this out there.